# Where to put WSDL and how to reference for SoapClient

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento-1.5, soap-client

I'm certain this is a dumb newbie question, but this is the first time I'm working with SOAP, so I guess I qualify.  I'm having a heck of a time trying to load a local WSDL file from within my PHP class.  I don't understand where it is looking for the file or how I can reference it locally.  I could put the absolute path using the full website url, but that seems like overkill and it would ONLY work on this site.  I'd prefer to reference the file using a relative path.

I'm using PHP with a Magento store.  The class that handles communication with the SOAP server is `Namespace_Module_Model_Carrier_Fedex_Addressvalidation`, which is located at `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Carrier/Fedex/Addressvalidation.php`.  An instance of this class is instantiated using `Mage::getModel('shippingrates/carrier_fedex_addressvalidation')` from within the `Namespace_Module_Model_Carrier_Fedex` class.  The WSDL location is defined at the top of the address validation class:

```
protected $_wsdl = 'AddressValidationService_v2.wsdl';
```

Within the constructor of the model I initialize the SoapClient:

```
$this->_client = new SoapClient($this->_wsdl);
$this->_client->__setLocation($this->getServiceLocation());//returns a remote URL for their test server
```

The file is located in the same directory as the **Addressvalidation.php** file, but I have also tried locating it in the same directory as the **Fedex.php** script as well as at **app/code/local/** but nothing works.  I have tried setting the WSDL variable to **./AddressValidationService_v2.wsdl** as well as various other options but I always get an exception like this:

```
Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from './AddressValidationService_v2.wsdl' : failed to load external entity
```

If someone can please help me understand the scope and where the SoapClient looks for the files I think I'll have a better understanding of where to put them and how to reference them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the WSDL file points to the URL not to a local file.

So if you have a web service set up and running on your local PC, this is how you could set up your client for testing:

```
<?php

$wsdl = "http://127.0.0.1/api/service.wsdl";

$options = [
    'trace'      => 1,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
];

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

$return = $client->getDetails([$id = 1234]);

echo "Request headers: " . print_r($client->__getLastRequestHeaders(), 1), "\n";
echo "Request: " . $client->__getLastRequest(), "\n";
echo "Response headers: " . print_r($client->__getLastResponseHeaders(), 1), "\n";
echo "Response: " . $client->__getLastResponse(), "\n";
```

This is actually from a working PHP script on my computer. I test my own **SoapServer** this way and it works. "`getDetails`" is a method defined in WSDL file and it expects one parameter, which I pass as `$id`.

The debugging lines are output after the call, which is very helpful to me.

Comment: In this case the WSDL file is stored locally but the server to which all requests are sent is remote.  To do this, I'm initializing the SoapClient with a *location* parameter (see question above...I edited it to reflect this).

Comment: In order to keep development moving along I put the file in the root of the webserver and reference it using **http:/ /localhost/wsdl/AddressValidationService_v2.wsdl**.  Now I get an error saying **Couldn't find in 'http:/ /localhost/wsdl/AddressValidationService_v2.wsdl'**....couldn't find WHAT??

Comment: You need to poing to a full url, including http:// and not just 'localhost/wsdl/'

Comment: Just try to access your wsdl with a browser, put the http://localhost/wsdl/AddressValidationService_v2.wsdl in the browser address and if you can see your wsdl file in browser then just use that url in your SoapClient. If you cannot see it it browser that there is a problem - either your apache server is not running of address is incorrect

Comment: I am...it was turning my URLs into links and dropping the protocol portion.  I put a space between the 2 slashes so it doesn't do that in the comment, but what I'm actually using in my script is correct.  It's finding the WSDL file now but I'm getting the new **Couldn't find in...** error.  I don't know what that's complaining about.

Comment: This most likely means that your wsdl file is invalid. It's not easy to create a valid wsdl file by hand. Do you use any tool to generate a wsdl?

Comment: I didn't generate it...it was sent do me by FedEx when I signed up for a dev key.  Am I supposed to modify it to suit my needs?  If so, what do I need to change?

Comment: I see, so the web service is not on your local server then. I think they send it to you just so you can get an idea what functions they have, what parameters they expect, what objects are returned, etc. It was not meant to be actually used for testing. Your only choice now would be to actually point the wsdl to the actual one of the fedex server, I mean point to the read file and try if your client works with it.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes more sense.  They never told me the URL to get to their WSDL file and all their code samples reference a local copy, but perhaps that's wrong.  I'll contact them for more help.  Thanks for all of yours!

Comment: pointing the uri to a file location works just fine. Be sure that a) permissions are set correctly and b) you use the absolute path to the file (or the correct relative path).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a mis configuration in my Apache server.  It was redirecting my request to "localhost" over to another virtual host on the same server.  When I tried loading the WSDL file from my browser it worked fine but from the script on the server it did not.  It's still not working, but I've made progress at least.